# Как разбить датасет на train, validation и test выборки, сохранив порядок записей?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

Помогите отсортировать данные для нейроной сети. Нашел как сделать срез данных в интернете, вписал в свой код, работает, ниже пример. Но мне нужно, чтобы данные не хаотично отбирались. Первые 70 процентов в тренировочный датасет, 15 в валидационый, и последние 15 в тестовый.

```
p=0.8
trainDataset = dataset.sample(frac=p,random_state=0)
testDataset = dataset.drop(trainDataset.index)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [np.split()](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
train, validate, test = np.split(df, [int(.7*len(df)), int(.85*len(df))])
```

---

пример:

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 3)), columns=list("abc"))

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
    a  b  c
0   1  1  9
1   2  8  8
2   9  4  7
3   7  2  6
4   4  5  9
.. .. .. ..
95  7  5  7
96  1  6  3
97  7  2  7
98  9  4  5
99  5  3  2

[100 rows x 3 columns]

In [27]: train, validate, test = np.split(df, [int(.7*len(df)), int(.85*len(df))])

In [28]: train.shape
Out[28]: (70, 3)

In [29]: validate.shape
Out[29]: (15, 3)

In [30]: test.shape
Out[30]: (15, 3)
```